# there is some way to make my own item in xml?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, android-xml

i work on android-studio project, and my question is about if
**there is some way i can define in xml type of some item that contain 
few edit text and buttons**, and open listview that contain the item i create?
somthing like :

```
<item
<Editext(some setting)/>
<Edittext 1(some setting)/>
<Button(some setting)/>
/>
```

and then some **adapter** that adjust or something like that, that i can add to ListView.

i saw in youtube some videos that try to explain that but i get stock.. i dno't really get this.

Answer (score 0):

This took my a while to figure out, but it works.
Create your Layout file just however you want. Save it as `res/layout/something.txt`. Example:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:text="hello"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/text1"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="world"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/text2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Use it in your code as follows:

```
LinearLayout mainLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
// inflate your container
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.something, null);
// you can make changes to the elements like this:
TextView txt1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
TextView txt2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
view.setTag(tag);
// add to main layout
mainLinearLayout.addView(view);
```

Where `tag` is an unique integer to identify the View. You don't need to set the tag if you're using the container only once.

I didn't use an Adapter when I made this. I just used a `ScrollView` to make a continous list of entries. Change this to your needs.